# Kafka java UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PART error intermittent

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I use Kafka in my Java Application.

When I send message to Kafka to use Producer, sometimes throw `UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PART` execption then resend message, but it will fail with `TIMEOUT` execption.

But if run it again, it will work normally.
This happens very intermittently..

My Producer Setting:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", servers);
props.put("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getCanonicalName());
props.put("value.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getCanonicalName());
props.put("metadata.fetch.timeout.ms", "10000");

producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("log", message), (metadata, exception) -> {
  if(exception != null) {
    LOGGER.error("Failed to send log - " + message, exception);
    LOGGER.debug("Resend log - " + message);
    send(message);
  }
});
```

I don't know what cause about this problem... 
Why is this?

Comment: Can you share the full error trace?

Comment: I couldn't capture stack log.. It's not an error now. If it happens again, I will

Comment: Are the addresses in your `servers` variable actually all part of the same cluster? Do you have auto topic creation enabled?

Comment: Uhm.. `servers' are my multiple server addresses, but not sure they are part of the same cluster. How to check that??
And I don't have auto topic creation enabled. What property that ??

Comment: And I want to know when `UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PART` occurs !